# Do I need the XBOX-LIVE SDK to publish a game in the Creators Program?

Tags: xbox-live

Knowing than a game as a UWP app can already run on the XBOX One, do I need to compile my game linking to the XBOX LIVE SDK if I want to publish my game through the Creators program?

- I'm not going to implement leaderboards,
- I'm not going to implement any social link,
- I'm not going to implement any networking at all.
- All I'm going to implement is some serious kicks in a local fighting
  game, using the best technology there is for gaming: DirectX 11.

Any information is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do need to add Xbox Live to your game to publish it through the Xbox Live Creators Program. Full details are captured on the table [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/games/xbox/docs/xboxlive/get-started/developer-program-overview#heading-4).

Comment: Thanks!!!! I had read that particular web page before, but aside explaining what can be done and what cannot be done, it never quite explicitly specified if the XBOX Live SDK was a requirement. Most likely, I misunderstood.

Comment: The important note is that in the Feature Table, Sign-in and User Identity are specified as REQUIRED for Xbox Live Creators Program.